# Can I send email on the Internet using postfix on a localhost without real hostname?

Tags: email, postfix

I have installed postfix on my local machine that has ubuntu 12.04 installed.

When I try to send email on the internet, all mails remain in queue and are reporting "Connection timed out" or "host unreachable".

I just want to know if it is possible to configure postfix (an how) in order to be able to send emails this way.

My computer is assigned a dynamic IP from the ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Many ISPs block outgoing mail to prevent getting on a blacklist. Please contact your ISP to check if this is the case.

If this is the case, you could use your ISP's SMTP server as a smarthost.